# Replace data in an Excel file using macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file which contains some data in a 2d array.

[image: Excel document]

What I want to do is to create a macro which can replace the asterisk '*' by the header of the column of the table (toto, or tata, or titi).

Comment: Replace asterisk with what exactly? I'm unclear as to what you are wanting. Do you simply want to replace every asterisk with the header name for that column?

Comment: Exactly sir, so it will be for the line 1 ('tata'), line 2 ('toto') and so on

Comment: So just for extra clarity, you want the data after the macro to look like: first line of data (1   38   345   tata) second line (2   toto  367    345) etc.?

Comment: Just curious, why ask for a macro and tag this with VBA if you don't know how to implement such a solution? Did you really mean "macro"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just worksheet tools (no VBA):

- `Ctrl-F`
- Find what = ~*
- `Find All`
- `Ctrl-A` to select all the Find results
- `Close` the Find dialog
- Assuming your headers in row two, and assuming the cursor lands in column C somewhere (mine did twice, YMMV), type
  formula `=C$2`
- Press `Ctrl-Enter`

Comment: + 1 For a Non VBA Solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set oRange = ws.Cells

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:="~*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        '~~> Assuming that the headers are in row 2
        aCell.Value = Cells(2, aCell.Column)
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                '~~> Assuming that the headers are in row 2
                aCell.Value = Cells(2, aCell.Column)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: And how can I implement this in Excel, since I have never done it before ?

Comment: You paste this code in a module. Replace "Sheet1" in the above code with the relevant sheetname which has the data. Also change `2` in `aCell.Value = Cells(2, aCell.Column)` to whatever row the headers are in and finally run the macro :)

Comment: Also I am using `Set oRange = ws.Cells` for the complete sheet. If you want you can change it to the relevant table range. For example `Set oRange = ws.Range("B2:E6")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way I came up with.

```
i = 3
While Cells(2, i).Value <> ""
    Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(6, i)).Select

    Selection.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:=Cells(2, i).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Cells(x,y): x refers to row, y refers to column.

A more refined range select can be used instead of this basic one to have the code choose the appropriate range.

To implement in excel simply open up the code window and paste this code in the desired macro/subroutine.

Comment: Bryan Looping through the cells is slower than using the inbuilt `.Find` and `.FindNext`. :) Maybe you would like to see this? http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Of Course, the speed wouldn't matter if there are very few cells :)

Comment: You might also want to see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-not-using-select

Comment: Speed will in this case be based on the number of columns, assuming he doesn't have a huge number of columns the difference between our run-times will likely be negligible. And while I am sure .Find is in many ways better than my admittedly simple suggestion, I prefer to post things that are easily readable and understandable. My answer was simply taking how Excel does its "Find and Replace" feature, and adding loop for each column. Again the intent of my answer was to be basic and simple.